# Azure Mobile Backend connection issue on ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-mobile-services, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on an ASP.Net Core web app and I try to connect it via an Azure Mobile Backend.

The backend is working well with other Windows Desktop applications.
Also the backend was working well till now with ASP.Net Core v2.0.
Yesterday I installed the ASP.Net Core 2.1 SDK and I updated the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget package from 2.0 to 2.1.2 and since then I am receiving the following exception:
MobileServiceInvalidOperationException - "The server did not provide a response with the expected content."

Can you tell me any solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

> Also the backend was working well till now with ASP.Net Core v2.0. Yesterday I installed the ASP.Net Core 2.1 SDK and I updated the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget package from 2.0 to 2.1.2 and since then I am receiving the following exception: MobileServiceInvalidOperationException - "The server did not provide a response with the expected content."

According to your description, your Azure Mobile Backend could work as expected with  ASP.Net Core v2.0. AFAIK, mobile backend just provides a simple way for you to expose your Table/API endpoints. Moreover, how did your web app connect with mobile backend, using HttpClient or [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/)?

For a simple way to troubleshoot this issue, you could Enable diagnostics logging for your Azure Mobile App to retrieve the detailed error message to narrow this issue, details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log).

Comment: I think I am using the latest Mobile Client SDK, by installing the latest Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client (v4.0.2) nuget package.

Finally I could make it work by downgrading every ASP.NetCore related nuget packages to the latest v2.0.x versions and also downgrading the target framework to .Net Core 2.0.

I will try again the .NetCore 2.1 after some updates, hopefully it will be fixed.

Comment: I too "fixed" this issue by downgrading from .Net Core 2.1 to .Net Core 2.0.  My main reason for upgrading from 2.0 to 2.1 in the first place was because I needed SignalR.  As it turned out, I found I could use SignalR with no changes to my code in 2.0 as well - I just followed this advice: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but no solution. I traced it down to the following line of code in `MobileServiceHttpClient` code in the `SendRequestAsync(...)` function.

```
// If there was supposed to be response content and there was not, throw        
if (ensureResponseContent)
{
   long? contentLength = null;

   if (response.Content != null)
   {
      contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
   }

   if (contentLength == null || contentLength <= 0)
   {
        throw new MobileServiceInvalidOperationException("The server did not provide a response with the expected content.", request, response);
   }
}
```

Looking at the `response.Content.Headers.ContentLength` it is `null`. Running the app as a 2.0 Core project, the value is filled in correctly. What is is strange is that the content is there.

If you drill into the private members some of them are set correctly.

```
catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
{
    //content will contain the correct json but the ContentLenth is null!?!
    string content = await msioe.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

It is a 2.1 Core issue. Hopefully they fix it.

Comment: I did create an issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/467

Comment: Thanks for raising that with MS @Stef.  The response from MS is "we won't fix this".  Ouch!!   Moving back to .NET Core 2.0 will be painful for me.  Does anyone understand what it is about the move to 2.1 that broke Azure Mobile Apps?  Maybe that would give us a clue for a workaround..?

Comment: We ended up just replacing the Azure Mobile Client with our own extended HttpClient class. You lose the sync ability but for reads, writes and so on it works.

Comment: @EdBarnes ; Good idea. I was thinking on creating a client based on RestEase.

Comment: @MrBlueSky ; you could just download the source code and include this project as a reference in your example project. Maybe I'll also do that next week.